# PGP Encryption Marketing Cloud File Transfer

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, automation, encryption

I'm attempting to setup a file transfer activity from the Marketing Cloud Safehouse to our FTP Export Folder, encrypted. However, to do this, I have to enable a 'Customer Public Key'. On the activity it shows 'No Items' in the drop down. Is this something I need to setup or have Salesforce enable? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upload your PGP key under Key Management in Setup.

Select *Asymmetric*, fill out *Name* and *External Key* fields, and upload the file containing your public PGP key:
[image]
 Find more information on how to do this, on [these pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_key_management.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null).

> When creating an upload file transfer activity that moves a file from
>   your Marketing Cloud account to an external location, you can encrypt
>   the file using PGP or GPG encryption. Upon execution of the activity,
>   Marketing Cloud encrypts the specified file and moves it to the
>   specified location.

Once created, the key will appear in the drop down of your file transfer activity

Comment: Thank you Lukas! When I attempted to configure/create the SSH key for the encryption, I got a saving error message stating "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object". Do you have any idea what that means?

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 - you should not be adding an asymmetric key, not ssh key. See my updated answer above

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 - please remember to mark answers as accepted. I can see some of your questions have really good answers - without being marked as accepted. It is beneficial for the community to be able to identify the good answers.

Comment: Good Call Lukas. Sorry new to the community. I'll go through and ensure answers are accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 - no worries, we all have been new here at some point

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot above, the only thing that you missed is to select the Radio Button "PGP", following which your Automation/Activity would have encrypted the File in PGP format.

Comment: I did select that but even when I did it still didn't work.